# Canvas shapes becoming aliased when re-drawn in safari

Tags: html, safari, canvas

I'm drawing a simple progress indicator using canvas. When the element is drawn for the first time it looks all nice and anti-aliased, but when drawn a second time, it loses it's anti-aliasing. Anyone know what could be going on here?

```
function drawProgress(id, percent) {
            var selected = $(safeID(id)).is('.selected');

            var canvas = $(safeID("CANVAS_" + id));
            var ctx = $(canvas)[0].getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect();

            if ( selected ) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
            }
            else {
                ctx.fillStyle = "#99a7ca";
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#99a7ca";
            }

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(canvas.width()/2.0, canvas.height()/2.0, canvas.width()/2.0-1, 0, Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(canvas.width()/2.0, canvas.height()/2.0, canvas.width()/2.0-1, 0, Math.PI*2.0, false);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify dimensions to `clearRect`.

Comment: lol. I just noticed that then rushed back here to answer it. Too slow i guess :)

Comment: I suppose this could answer people's question about removing anti-aliasing. Just draw the same shape 5 times and the pixels with partial alpha channels will fill themselves in to appear aliased.